# События мыши на jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouse-event

Всем привет!
Прошу помочь с решением простой задачки.
Мне нужно, чтобы наведении курсора мыши на кнопку она меняла стиль и при отведении возвращалась в исходное положение.
Через jQuery я создал вот такой код для mouseover:

```
 `$(function(){
    function changeStyleButton(){
        $('#entrance').css({
            'color': 'green',
            'font-size': '20px',
            'border': '5px solid #FFD700',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 5px 7px blue'
        })
    }

    $('#entrance').on('mouseover', function(){
        changeStyleButton()
    })
})
```

При наведении он срабатывает и все.
Как написать, чтобы при отведении возвращался изначальный стиль.
Спасибо.)

Comment: Нужно оперировать классами, а не стилями, и стили прописывать классу. При наведении добавил класс, при отведении - убрал класс.

Comment: Зачем имитировать то, что можно сделать псевдоклассом `:hover` в css?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#entrance')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).addClass("hovering");
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).removeClass("hovering");
    });
})
```

```css
.hovering {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #FFD700;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 7px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="entrance">AAAAAAAAA</div>
```